# Check changes in code without online repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, source-code-protection

is there a way to track the changes in the code without an online repository in visual studio? because we can't use an online repository like GitHub because of security issues. I hope someone can help me thanks!

Comment: Why not use a local Git repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a local repository or a repo on a local server.  You can use Git or SVN for free.  Both are open source. Also, GitHub or GitLab can be installed locally but may not be free.  Make sure that it is backed up some how.

Here is one example https://www.toolsqa.com/git/create-git-repository/ and there are many others.

Others you might be interested in are Mercurial, Helix Core, etc. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version-control_software

Comment: It's 2021, please don't suggest that someone uses subversion! You could have suggested Mercurial instead

Comment: I know of large companies that still use it.  Besides, Mercurial is not that popular anymore.  Bitbucket no longer  uses it.  In any case, the answer meant to say that a repo can be installed locally, not to suggest which exact repo to use.  There are many different ones depending on the user's needs and budget.